# How to apply a function on a Series

Tags: python, pandas, apply, series

Given a Series `s`:

```
                  Name
0     Tennessee Oilers
1     Tennessee Titans
2  Washington Redskins
```

I would like a apply a function to rename the values.

```
translate = {
    'Houston Oilers': 'Tennessee Titans',
    'Tennessee Oilers': 'Tennessee Titans'
}

s = s.apply(lambda x: translate.get(x, x))
```

And this raises:

> TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be
>   hashed",    u'occurred at index 0')

Had I applied this on DataFrame's column instead, this would have worked.

I thought I was doing this according to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) Can you correct me please?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, the only way this would fail like this is if you did `pd.DataFrame(s).apply(lambda x: translate.get(x, x))`

Comment: For some reason my 1-column Series read as DataFrame (with `read_csv`) and was the very reason why my code broke. Thanks!

Comment: If you want a series then pass param `squeeze=True` to `read_csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) to perform the lookup:

```
In [204]:
translate = {
    'Houston Oilers': 'Tennessee Titans',
    'Tennessee Oilers': 'Tennessee Titans'
}
s.map(translate)

Out[204]:
0    Tennessee Titans
1                 NaN
2                 NaN
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

The reason `s = s.apply(lambda x: translate.get(x, x))` fails is because the lambda here is a pandas `Series` and this cannot be used as a key lookup value for the error reason given as it cannot be hashed which dict keys must be.

**EDIT**

Actually I can't reproduce your error:

```
In [210]:
s.apply(lambda x: translate.get(x, x))

Out[210]:
0       Tennessee Titans
1       Tennessee Titans
2    Washington Redskins
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

the above works fine

**Edit 1**

To keep non-existing values you can call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas.Series.dropna) and [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html#pandas.Series.update):

```
In [219]:
s.update(s.map(translate).dropna())
s

Out[219]:
0       Tennessee Titans
1       Tennessee Titans
2    Washington Redskins
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

When you read a csv using `read_csv` it returns a df even if it only has a single column, if you want a series then pass param `squeeze=True`:

```
In [223]:
t="""Name
Tennessee Oilers
Tennessee Titans
Washington Redskins"""
type(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), squeeze=True))

Out[223]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

**Edit 2**

Your error occurred because you called apply on a single column df:

```
pd.DataFrame(s).apply(lambda x: translate.get(x, x))
```

So this is different to a Series where `apply` iterates over each value which can be hashed but here it's passing the entire `Series` which cannot be hashed, it would work if you did this:

```
In [227]:
pd.DataFrame(s).apply(lambda x: translate.get(x['Name'], x['Name']), axis=1)

Out[227]:
0       Tennessee Titans
1       Tennessee Titans
2    Washington Redskins
dtype: object
```

passing `axis=1` performs row-wise value passing

Comment: Thx, but I'd rather keep the values if not in `translate`.